# i am playing a video using video view , i want to play it providing a skip play option on the screen

Tags: android

The video view is in full screen. I want the display in half of the screen and a skip button at the bottom of the screen which will skip the video.

Answer (score 1):

Just add [button](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html) and [progressbar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html) to the layout you have video view on and add controls for them.